# does http:keep-alive keep the php resources open or does it free all the resources?

Tags: php, apache, apache2, keep-alive

I am using http keep-alive on a apache server,
Lets say I ask it to keep the connections open upto 2 minutes...
Now, if the connection is created and idle for a minute, will the resources held by php,
like mysql connections, file handles, etc., will be freed or will they survive too ?

Comment: Thing is, you couldn't identify your hold resources in a new request. I guess it just instructs appache to not exit the process that has been started to handle your requests. But as in HTTP 1.1 this keep-alive option isn't used anymore. B/c no seperate processes are started to deal with different requests. Interesting question. Hope somebody can give a definite answer to it. Cause a quick search didn't reveal "simple" answers.

Comment: its not that its not in use anymore, its made default... So there is an option in httpd.conf file which can enable it and tell it for how much time to keep it open...  And yeah, I hope someone gives me a real answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confirmed. Keep-Alive is a mechanism to prevent costly TCP connection negotiation. Your PHP process/thread starts as normal and needs to allocate all resources as usual.

Regarding a high load situation, it might be wise to even keep the keep-alive period not too high: All connection requests compete for free connection slots of your server. If all slots are in-use by keep-alive connections, other users might not connect.

But, as usual, the optimal amount of slots and good keep-alive period depends on your specific load situation.

Comment: Yo :) Confirmed :)  
I did some tests the following day too... I observed the same...

Comment: Thx for the confirmed confirmation! Could you please one answer as being OK?

Answer (score 1):

no , http keep-alive save resources of tcp connection . php and mysql will not even aware of that connection is open , when you will make next request it would be fast because time spend resolving ip address , and opening new tcp connection will be saved all this things remain with apache.